# Python script execution error in Windows 7 32 bit system

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have installed python 2.7.10 in my windows 7 32 bit system. I have created a small script test.py and saved it in the folder D:\python27. Now when I execute `test.py` from windows cmd it runs fine. But when I run python from the command line and then execute the same command `test.py` I get the error:

```
File "<stdin>",line 1, in<module>NameError:name 'test' is not defined.
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not how you execute a python script. Instead of starting the python interpreter and then typing

`test.py`

you have to type

`python test.py`

directly into the command line.

What you did is starting the python interpreter. This is for directly typing and executing python commands in the shell/cmd.

Comment: I you think this answer fits your question, do me a favor and mark it as the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can not execute a python script from python interpreter as from the terminal,

from terminal it is:

```
python test.py
```

In your python command line:

You can only import it as `import test`

or if you have args in it you can use os

```
import os

os.system("test.py")
```